# why fail to change the factor into date time timestamp

Tags: r, timestamp, lubridate

Used read.csv file into R, below columns are in factor format by using class() , but need to  calculate the lead time, which is the time difference, so need to transfer to date format, right? but when using library lubridate to change the format from factor to Date, the data all become NA, why is this happening and how to solve? thanks!

A

2017-06-12 13:38:00

NA

`test<-dmy(mydata$package_receiving_at)`

```
class(test)
```

`>[1] "Date"`

```
test
>NA
```

Comment: Try to change your factor to character first, using `as.character()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still receive NA, even if using as.character() first

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add the output of `dput(mydata$package_receiving_at)`. This will help to reproduce the problem and to check the type of your input data. Thank you.

Comment: Is the function `dmy()` from the `lubridate` package?

Comment: @uwe block, yes, it is

Comment: your strings are not in `dmy` format (day - month - year).  You should use `ymd_hms()` to do your conversion.